# How can I return a new array in JavaScript and add to each item in the array? (WITHOUT THE MAP METHOD)

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have to return a new array. Here is the original.

```
const animals = ['panda', 'turtle', 'giraffe', 'hippo', 'sloth', 'human'];
```

I have to return a new array where each string is prepended with 'baby '

I need to use a function but I'm not allowed to use the .map() method.

This is the current code I'm running:

```
function convertToBaby(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    return `baby ${arr[i]}`;
  }
}

const animals = ["panda", "turtle", "giraffe", "hippo", "sloth", "human"];

console.log(convertToBaby(animals));
```

I would imagine it returns the new array, but it only returns baby panda.
What is going on?

Comment: Not allowed? By whom?

Comment: `return` exits the function immediately. Your loop won't get past `i` being 0. You have to declare a variable in the function, initialize it to an empty array, and then populate it with the strings in a loop like the one you have.

Comment: ^ and then return that populated array from the function.

Comment: function convertToBaby(arr) {
  return arr.map((e)=> `baby ${e}`)
}

const animals = ["panda", "turtle", "giraffe", "hippo", "sloth", "human"];

console.log(convertToBaby(animals));

Comment: @MahadevMirasdar did you read the giant words in the title "WITHOUT THE MAP METHOD"?

Comment: function convertToBaby(arr) {
let out = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    out.push(`baby ${arr[i]}`);
  }
   return out;
  }

const animals = ["panda", "turtle", "giraffe", "hippo", "sloth", "human"];

console.log(convertToBaby(animals));

Answer (score 0):

The `return` keyword automatically exits the function, so the `for` loop only returns the first element.

If you want to use a loop, you can use:

```js
function convertToBaby(arr) {
  const newArray = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    newArray.push(`baby ${arr[i]}`);
  }
  return newArray;
}
```